# Wordpress PHP String replace

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to show a posts category as a class, I have got this to generate. However I want to replace the spaces with an hyphen.

```
<div class="blog-item <?php 
  $categories = get_the_category();

  foreach($categories as $category)
  { 
    echo strtolower($category->cat_name) . ' ';
 }
 ?>"
```

This then outputs the following:-

```
<div class="blog-item blog category 1">
```

I would however prefer this to be:-

```
<div class="blog-item blog-category-1">
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would echo category slug rather than category name.

So:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

foreach($categories as $category) { 
  echo $category->slug;
}
```

Or if you have only one category:

```
echo get_the_category()[0]->slug;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

`echo strtolower($category->cat_name) . ' ';`

TO

```
echo $category->slug.' ';
```

If you don't want to use slug then replace the line

TO

```
echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$category->cat_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress default function "sanitize_title_with_dashes()" to replace spaces with hyphen - read more details from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/

```
<?php 
$categories = get_the_category(); 
foreach($categories as $category)
{
  ?>
  <div class="blog-item <?= strtolower(sanitize_title_with_dashes($category->cat_name)); ?>">

  </div>
  <?php 
}
?>
```